# PHP insert associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I would need to insert an associative array into my existing code, to make an HTTP request.

My code at the moment:

```
$payload =[
    'method_id' => 2,
    'api_key'   => 5,
];
$res = $client->post('some.website', [,
    'form_params' => [
        foreach($this->payload as $key => $s_key) {
            $key => $s_key;
        }
    ],
]);
```

How to make now sure, each element of the $payload array is inserted into the form_params array?

I tried using:

```
foreach ($this->payload as $s_key => $key) {
    //?!
}
```

But I don't know how to proceed inside the form_params element?

Using the payload array directly inside form elements is resulting into this:

```
    "form_params" => [
        0 => array:2 [
          "method_id" => 2
          "api_key" => 5
        ]
    ]
```

What I would need is something like this:

```
    "form_params" => [
          "method_id" => 2
          "api_key" => 5
    ]
```

Comment: How about: `'form_params' => $payload`, since it already is an associated array?

Comment: This won't work since I need the parameters directly in the forms_param array. Using the way you mentioned results in: array:1 `[▼
  "form_params" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "method_id" => 2
      "api_key" => 5
    ]
  ]
]`

Comment: No it won't, unless the `$payload` doesn't actually look like you're showing or if you did something like `'form_params' => [$payload]` (which is not what I suggested). Demo: https://3v4l.org/ohCsW

Comment: You also have a comma to many in: `'some.website', [,`. It should be `'some.website', [`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I edited my first post.

Comment: You can't be doing what we suggest, or your `$payload`-array can't look like you say. Here's a better demo: https://3v4l.org/ie27g. Please copy/paste the code your now using when you get that result (and  share the result of `var_dump($payload)` right before you do that call as well). The code in your question can't be your actual code, since it has syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to just use the `$payload` variable directly, like so:

```
$res = $client->post('some.website', [
    'form_params' => $payload,
]);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you seem to be getting that extra array in-between the `'form_params'` key and the "payload"? See the code here:  [https://3v4l.org/JMNHc](https://3v4l.org/JMNHc), I use the `$payload` variable as above and the payload associative array ends up directly under the `'form_param'` key.

Comment: I think the OP's code looks different from the code in the question, since the OP claims to get a result, while the code in the question would throw a syntax error (the trailing comma). I'm bailing now. Don't want to fall deeper into the rabbit whole :-p